# VF controller not maintaining instance variable value

Tags: visualforce, controller, viewstate, instance

```java
public without sharing class PaymentSuccessController {
    public Boolean emailSent = false;
    private List<String> rlis;

    public List<String> getReceiptLineItems() {
        if (rlis != null) {
            return rlis;
        }

        rlis = new List<String>();
        // populate rlis
        return rlis;
    }

    public void SendEmail() {
        if (!this.emailSent) {
            this.emailSent = true;
            //send email
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<apex:page controller="PaymentSuccessController" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" cache="false">
  <body style="margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;">
    <div style="margin: 20px 0 0 0;">
      <table class="hasborder">
        <apex:repeat value="{!ReceiptLineItems}" var="lineItem">         
        <tr>
          <td class="hasborder" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 2px;">${!lineItem.fees}</td>
        </tr>
        </apex:repeat>   
      </table>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
      <apex:form id="form" >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!SendEmail}" value="Send Email"/>
      </apex:form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

I attached a snippet of my vf page and controller below. The page displays line items for a receipt using a getter method. This works fine and if the user refreshes the page I test to see if that List has already been populated. If so, I return it. This works fine also as the view state is maintaining that instance value. However, when the user clicks on the SendEmail button, that function tries to set a flag so that the email isn't sent twice. That instance variable is not be maintained by the view state.  Why is this? How I can determine that a user is simply refreshing the page?

Comment: if you mean by "refreshing the page" the user clicks the "reload" icon or command on the browser?

Comment: yes, the user reloads the page through the browser

Comment: refreshing the page through the browser instantiates a new version of the controller and all viewState is lost. If you don't want them to click SendEmail twice, you need to preserve that state in the database

Comment: refreshing the page does maintain my rlis variable.  However, that method can only set an instance variable the first time it's called.  Very strange.

Comment: refreshing the page should re-populate rlis from presumably the database